# Asymptotic expansion involving a matrix equation

Tags: linear-algebra, asymptotics, matrix-equations

Let $b = [b_1,b_2,b_3,...b_n]^T$
$A = [a_{ij}]_{n \times n}$ such that $a_{i,j} = 1\forall 1\le i,j \le n$

$C = [c_{ij}(\lambda)]_{n \times n}$ such that $c_{ij}(\lambda) = O(\frac{1}{\lambda})$

$A+C$ is known to be a symmetric positive semi definite matrix

$I_n$ is an $n\times n$ Identity matrix

$e = [e_1,e_2,e_3,...e_n]^T$

$$b = (A+C+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}I_n)^{-1}e$$

I am trying to find an asymptotic expansion for $b_i$

Show that $b_i = O(\lambda)$.

For example If I take matrix $C$ as all zeros, $A$ is given as all ones, and the case $n=2$ I get $$b_i = O(\lambda)$$

Is there any good argument to generalize for any $n$, that $b_i = O(\lambda)$?

PS: The elements of all matrices are non negative, except matrix $e$, which can
take negative values.

Comment: Are you interested in the case $\lambda \to 0$ or $\lambda \to \infty$ here?

Comment: @FedericoPoloni : $\lambda \to \infty$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re [your answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/365990/1898):

Statement 1 follows from [Weyl's inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weyl%27s_inequality#Weyl%27s_inequality_about_perturbation) and $\rho_1(C) = O(\lambda^{-1})$.

$2 \implies 3$ seems problematic; what if $C = \frac{1}{\lambda^3}I$, which should be possible given the definition of big-O? Then $\rho_1(M^{-1}) \sim \lambda^2 \not\in O(\lambda)$.

Statement 4 seems just the matrix norm inequality $\|M^{-1}e\| \leq \|M^{-1}\|\|e\|$.

Comment: $M$ is positive definite, as $A+C$ is psd.

Comment: In question I had stated $A+C$ is known to be $psd$ so $M$ is a pd. Hope that solves the problem.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju Updated the counterexample.

Comment: Your example still assumes $\rho(M) = 0$ which is not possible.

Comment: $M$ is positive definite.

Comment: EDIT: Ok, fixed counterexample, hopefully.

Comment: Your counter example seems valid to me. Luckily in my problem $C$ goes as $\frac{1}{\lambda}$...perhaps $O$ is not suitable here, I should have used $\omega$ or something. I have a closed form expression for $C$ which is $\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju Still won't work. What if $C$ is entrywise $O(\lambda^{-1})$ but has an eigenvalue that goes like $O(\lambda^{-3})$? For instance, take $n>2$ and let $Q$ be an orthogonal matrix such that $Ef=f_1$, where $f$ is the vector of all ones and $f_1$ is the first column of $I$. Then $QAQ^{-1} = diag(n,0,0,...0)$. Take then $QCQ^{-1} = diag(0,\lambda^{-1},\lambda^{-3},\lambda^{-3},\dots,\lambda^{-3})$. Then if $Q$ is "complicated enough" all entries of $Q$ will scale like $\lambda^{-1}$, but $QMQ^{-1} = diag(n+\lambda^{-2},\lambda^{-1},\lambda^{-3},\lambda^{-3},\dots,\lambda^{-3})$.

Comment: @RajeshDachiraju That I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments and answer.

Answer (score 1):

**My proof** (some statements are without proof, for which I need references)

Let $X$ be any $n\times n$ square matrix and Let $\rho_1(X), \rho_2(X), \rho_3(X),...\rho_i(X),...\rho_n(X)$ denote the eigenvalues in descending order, of the matrix $X$.

Statement : 1* $$\rho_1(A+C) = n+O(1/\lambda)$$ $$\rho_i(A+C) = 0+O(1/\lambda),i = 2,3...n$$

Let $M = A+C+\frac{1}{\lambda^2}I_n$

Statement : 2 $$\rho_1(M) = n+O(\frac{1}{\lambda})$$ $$\rho_i(M) = 0+O(\frac{1}{\lambda}),i = 2,3,...n$$

statement : 3 $$\rho_1(M^{-1}) = O(\lambda),i = 1,2,3,...n-1$$ $$\rho_{n-1}(M^{-1}) = O(1)$$

statement : 4* The highest Eigen value of $M^{-1}$ is $O(\lambda)$, hence $b = M^{-1}e = O(\lambda)$, which means $b_i = O(\lambda), i = 1,2,3...n$

Statements 1 and 4, I have no proofs or references, which I need some help.
Statements 2 and 3 are true and sources readily available.